# How do I stop visual studio 2015 from minimizing automatically?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

When I rum my code in the ide (in the debug mode), the ide minimises automatically. It is quite annoying? How do I stop that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken this annoying behavior is set in the options . I think it is the Debug leaf of the options tree, just I do not remember the exact settting.